# hibernate two session synchronization

Tags: hibernate

hy all,

i have a webApplication do i use hibernate and Mysql.
two user is connected in the application, user1 --> Session1 , user2---> session2
session1 and session2 is a hibernate session.
my problem if user1 and user2 do this:

```
Criteria query = this.session.createCriteria(Azienda.class).setCacheable(false)
            .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);

    this.listAziende = query.list();
```

the first user has a list not empty but the second user has the liste empty
why?
i like do if user1 save a new row in table azienda whith session1, i like user2 see all new row in tale azienda.
this is a part of code java to get a session when a user do login

```
 public static synchronized ConnectionDb getInstance() {

    if (cDb == null) {
        log = LogFactory.getLogger(Login.class, "pubCompanyLogger");
        cDb = new ConnectionDb();
    }

    return cDb;
}
public Session openSession() {
    Session s = sf.openSession();
    s.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hy,
just i like say i have resolved this problem.
the solution is in hibernate.cfg.xml, i have put this:

```
<property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" >false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" >true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" >com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" >auto</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" >thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.discard_pc_on_close" >false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.jpaql_strict_compliance" >true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners" >false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" >org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" >false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_identifier_rollback" >false</property>
```

now all is ok